# Error with '|' in password using python script

Tags: batch-file, python-3.x

Friends,

I have created a python script for storing variables on servers.

When I run the following it runs properly

```
if server == '11':
    cmd1='p -ssh root@67.233.4.146 -pw "goorba12345"'
    os.system(cmd1)
```

This runs fine and I can open the server. This command opens putty and log me on the server.

But if the pasword have '|' then it is giving me error:

```
if server == '11':
    cmd1='p -ssh root@67.233.4.147 -pw "||||||goorba12345"'
    os.system(cmd1)
```

'goorba12345' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am on windows and opening putty sessions from this script. Any help is highly appreciated. Remember this will run command on DOS. I have tried to use bash escape sequence ^, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '|' is getting interpreted by the operating system, so it's trying to pipe the output of the p command to the goorba12345 command. You need to escape the '|' with '^' character:

```
cmd1='p -ssh root@67.233.4.147 -pw "^|^|^|^|^|^|goorba12345"'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if server == '11':
    cmd1='p -ssh root@67.233.4.147 -pw "^|^|^|^|^|^|goorba12345"'
    os.system(cmd1)
```